# MVC5 startup URL and routing -- not working on local

Tags: asp.net-mvc, localhost, http-status-code-404, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a project up and running fine on my website.  If I deploy now, everything works fine.  The issue is when I'm trying to run in debug mode on my local computer--the routing seems to be messed up.

Here is my project web configuration:

[image]

Route configuration:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
               name: "Default",
               url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
               defaults: new { controller = "PvP", action = "Play", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
           );

        }
```

On my main controller, named PvPController, is a method named Play no no parameters.

When I launch my project by starting to debug, the URL it goes to is this (ignore parenthesis):

(http)://localhost:64397/

Everything loads up fine since the routing knows to redirect this to /PvP/Play.

HOWEVER, if I type in (http)://localhost:64397/PvP/Play, I get a 404 not found error.  The same thing happens if I try to do call any action in the PvP controller, including click on any links on the page that does load up straight from the debugger.

What's interesting is that I have a different controller called PvPAdminController.  It has an action named PvPAdmin with no parameters.  If enter type in this:

(http)://localhost:64397/PvPAdmin/PvPAdmin

The action is hit without any problems.

Is there some kind of issue with my start action and project URL that is doing this?  Why is routing working for PvPAdminController but not PvPController?

Thanks!

Upon request here's some of the controller code.

```
 [InitializeSimpleMembership]
    public class PvPController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /PvP/

        public ActionResult Play()
        {
        ... a bunch of logic....
       return View(output);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Clean solution and rebuild solution once and try again,everything looks good,just to make sure.Share controller code also. Did you make any changes in web configuration?

Comment: Did clean, rebuild, restart computer, no differences.  Also no changes in web config--I rolled back to an older version of the file and compared, no differences.  What part of the controller code should I be posting?  There is a lot.

Comment: Provide Play action method code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, my solution was to change the localhost port number and let it create a new virtual directory around that.  I'm not entirely sure how this happened, but I think when I was messing around with the startup URL it remapped some of the files, which is why I was getting 404 errors.

Still, I'm curious as to why it could still connect to the main Play page when using the (http)://localhost:64397/ but not (http)://localhost:64397/PvP/Play .